# Translation of 白眼狼

Tags: meaning-in-context

[十里桃花三生三世](https://www.99lib.net/book/90/6548.htm)

[To-the-Sky-King-Tang-Qi.pdf](http://dl.oceanofpdf.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/OceanOfPDF.org_To-the-Sky-King-Tang-Qi.pdf)

> 可叹大师兄竟救了玄女，将一条**白眼狼**引入昆仑山。
>
> Unfortunately, First Apprentice had looked after Xuan Nu, taken her
>   in, and by so doing unleashed **white-eyed terror** upon Mount Kunlun.

I looked up 白眼狼 means

> ungrateful soul

How it can be translated into

> white-eyed terror

?

Comment: bkrs:白眼狼 thankless wretch
an ingrate
 ungrateful and vicious person,evidently translator combined word origin (still felt by Chinese readers) with context to come up with suitable English version

Comment: Why not translate 白眼狼 literally  as "white eyes wolf"?  calling someone with a "wolf's heart" means that person is evil, the term 狼 itself metaphorically  incorporated all the evil traits of people including viciousness, selfishness, greed and ungratefulness

Comment: 白眼 metaphorically means *terror* in Chinese. *White-eyed terror* is a good translation, as it combines the literal description (*white-eyed*) with the metaphorical description (*terror*), and the latter is used as an English noun. You cannot use *wolf* by itself without also explicitly mentioning it with *terror*, as *wolf* can range in meaning from *vicious* to *dominant, brave*.

Comment: @droooze I doubt 白眼 means “terror”. Any dictionary can support it?

Comment: @dan maybe you're right, I looked again and I can only find the meanings *hateful, abominable, disgusting, abhorrent*. 《漢語大詞典》＂表示鄙薄或厭惡。＂

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think “white-eyed terror” is a good translation. "ungrateful terror" is better here. we use 白眼狼 to describe someone who is not grateful in China.